# Need help identifying this microbe

Tags: cell-biology, microbiology, cell-culture, microscopy

[image: Image of cell line under 20x taken with a phone camera]

Sorry for the bad image, we don't have a camera hooked up to our culture room microscope yet. But Has anyone seen these kind of (what I'm assuming are) contaminating bacteria before? We see these from time to time in our transgenic A431D/MDA cell lines. They're not motile. They're not visible by eye so I'm assuming they're not fungi either. The media we maintain these cells in is supplemented with geneticin (G418) antibiotic for selecting the transgenic clones.

If you've come across these, could you also share how you dealt with them?

Comment: Have you searched the literature for geneticin resistant bacteria? Did you do a gram stain? I doubt anyone can identify the bacteria from that photograph. A wild guess might be possible (Acinetobacter?), but I don't see how that would really help you.

Comment: From a practical perspective, if you have contamination like that, the best course of action is to just dump the cells and start over. Go back to earlier passages in your frozen stock. If they're all contaminated, you may have to re-derive the cell line. It is extremely difficult to rid cells of contamination 100%. If even one viable cell remains, it can start multiplying again in culture. It's not impossible, it's just a **lot** of work.

Comment: What magnification are we looking at here? Many fungi (especially yeasts) are microscopic, and significantly smaller than your mammalian cells. If they are bacteria, you're not really going to narrow it down with much confidence by looking at microscope images alone. I'm seeing a couple of potential diplococcus pairs, but that doesn't get you much closer to a positive ID on it's own.

Comment: I'm assuming you are meaning the blob-like thing in the middle of the picture, below the senescent cell? If so, does it get bigger over time or you find a lot more of these with time? If not, then there's a good chance that it's not contamination, but something like an apoptotic cell or a lump of something from the FBS.

Comment: please update with 1) magnification of image, 2) which object your are asking about, 3) and other relevant information about media/culture/storage/etc.

Comment: @MattDMo - I agree with you completely. It would be nice to know what got in, though. There might be a clue as to how it got in.

Comment: @anongoodnurse but sometimes, you don't want to. I once worked for a pharma company doing QA investigations of environmental monitoring failures. In one case, they identified contamination in the air (in a non-critical area, fortunately) as *Gardnerella vaginalis*. No one had any desire to further investigate its source. We just called it "resulting from human presence in the area" and left it at that...

Comment: @MattDMo  - Oh my word, lol! That *is* a bit awkward...

Comment: Couldn't you draw ️ a circle around the microbe in question? Like, with whatever basic image software your computer ️ has.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you are referring to the blob thing in the middle of the pictures. Very hard if not impossible to say what is it. If I was you I would do a PCR on the 16S rRNA gene and send it for Sanger sequencing. the results can then be blasted against nrNuc databases in NCBI, you will have then your answer.